# Angular update @Input() Object

Tags: angular, object, input, angular-lifecycle-hooks, ngonchanges

I've got a GameStats Object of my self defined interface. If I change the value of a attribute the child component doesn't recognize it.
I found solutions with ngOnChanges which doesn't get fired, and with ngDoCheck which still contains the old values.

My example code:

app.component.html

```
<app-settings [gameStats]="gameStats"></app-settings>
```

app.component.ts (update attribute)

```
  onRunningStatusChanged(event: any) {
      this.gameStats.gameRunning = event;
  }
```

settings.component.ts

```
@Input() gameStats!: GameStats;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change detection doesn't do deep object comparison, it only checks if the reference is the same, and in your case it is. You might want to change the `onRunningStatusChanged` handler to this:

```
  onRunningStatusChanged(event: any) {
      this.gameStats = {...this.gameStats, gameRunning: event};
  }
```

This assigns a new object to `this.gameStats` that has all the properties, but with the `gameRunning` property overwritten.

Comment: I tried something similar before to reassign the object. What do the '...' do?

Comment: It's called [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals). It copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object.

Comment: This is valid one, but worth noting that this could cause an issue with object copying. `Spread operator` only deep copies object when data is not nested.

If your object contains nested data, it will make deep copy of top most data  and shallow copy of nested data.